# I need to show progressDialog on Fragment Android

Tags: android, fragment, progressdialog

How to show progress dialog in webView inside Fragment when every link is clicked?

With what I have tried only the first load progessdialog is shown, and then when I click on another link inside WebView, progressDialog is not working anymore.

Here there is my code:

```
public class Google extends SherlockFragment {
WebView mWebView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentberanda, container, false);
    mWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
    final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Loading...", "Please wait...", true);
    pd.setCancelable(false);


    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if (pd.isShowing()) {
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            //show your progressdialog here
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }
    });
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://googele.com");

    return rootView;
}
```

Is there anything wrong in my code ?

Comment: put pd.show(); in pagestarted and see

Comment: OMG is that simple ? it's working, thanks dude, i have working on it a few hours and I don't get it so simple, thanks

Comment: cool :) I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put pd.show in your `onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)`

Something like:

```
@Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        pd.show();
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
public class About27Fragment extends Fragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about_27, container, false);

    final WebView webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView_about27);
    final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", "Please wait, Loading Page...", true);


    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {}

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
            dialog.dismiss();
            String webUrl = webView.getUrl();
        }


    });

    webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com.mx");

    return rootView;
}
```

}